# How to redirect subdomain to a special port?

Tags: node.js, cloudflare, ghost, netdata

In my case, the host is one of my instances at Digital Ocean, but I am using Cloudflare as my DNS Sever.

I tried to redirect my domain and subdomain to special port, but not work.

Domain RSV setting(not working):

`Type: RSV
 Name: _http._tcp.mydomain.life
 Value: SRV 0 0 8080 mydomain.life <- ip is 128.99.12.34
 TTL: Auto`

Subdomain RSV setting(not working):

`Type: RSV
 Name: _http._tcp.mysub.
 Value: SRV 0 0 8080 othersubdomain.mydomain.life <- ip is 128.99.12.34
 TTL: Auto`

I have created the A record for mydomain.life and mysub.mydomain.life.

The result is, both of them don't redirect to 128.99.12.34:8080(netdata),

but just connect to 128.99.12.34(ghost)

Am I missing something?

Or any other solution can help me to redirect the domain/subdomain to special port?

Answer (score 0):

A record doesn't have port information.

to use SRV record you need a client that queries SRV records and do something with ip:port.

if you want to redirect something to ip:port you need to use some sort of reverse proxy or web server to handle it (nginx, haproxy, ...)